# angularjs - directives - determine on one directive which directive to run after by examine attribute

Tags: angularjs-directive

**Goal**: run 2 directives in a row the second directive will be determine by the first directive output

**Problem**: do it dynamically.

i want to make a core directive which will get:

```
<div field-directive="textbox" field-model="SomeModel"/>
```

in the core directive i want to use the template to return something like that:

```
<div >
                       <div>
                            <div >
                                {{fieldModel.Title}}:
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <div ng-model="fieldModel.Value" textbox />
                            </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
```

the problem i can't figure out how to write the value of the attribute `field-directive` which is `textbox` in the template, i need it because i want another directive to run on the output of this one.
my directive:

```
myapp.directive('fieldDirective', function()

    {
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            fieldModel: "=",
            fieldDirective: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.html(element.html().replace("field-directive", attr.fieldDirective));
        }
        template: 
        '<div ng-show="fieldModel.IsRelevant">\
                       <div>\
                            <div class="fieldTitle">\
                                {{fieldModel.Title}}:\
                            </div>\
                            <div>\
                                <div ng-model="fieldModel.Value" fieldDirective />\
                            </div>\
                       </div>\
                   </div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just for the case someone else will encounter a similar problem :
my solution was writing this data on the link function and then use compile function like that:

```
myapp.directive('fieldDirective',['$compile', function(compile)

{
  return{
    replace : true,
    scope : {
        fieldModel: "=",
        fieldDirective: "="
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {

          var strTemplate  =('<div ng-show="fieldModel.IsRelevant"><div><div class="fieldTitle">{{fieldModel.Title}}:</div><div><div ng-model="fieldModel.Value" placeHolder /></div></div></div>').replace("placeHolder", attr.fieldDirective);
          var e = angular.element(strTemplate);
        compile(e.contents())(scope);
        element.replaceWith(e);


    },
             }
}]
);
```